# gsub codification issues with UTF-8

Tags: ruby, encoding, gsub

I am trying to create a slug from some usernames in a DB migration.

```
nick = nick.gsub('á','a')
```

I really want change also `éíóúñ` to `eioun`.

Doing so, it doesn't work, I will get:

> incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with ASCII-8BIT string) (Encoding::CompatibilityError)

But, however I do, for example by adding force_encoding method, I always get encodings errors like:

> invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
>
> "\xF3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
>
> incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)

This just happends when I have a gsub for changing those vocals or the spanish ñ letter.

There's also a `encoding: utf-8` line on my file and data comes from a UTF-8 database. But nothing seems to help.

I've seen some questions on SO but anything I try to do doesn't fix it.

By the way, this is not rails related.

Comment: Which ruby version do you use?

Comment: There is no intersection between the set of fun programming tasks and the set of encoding related programming tasks.

Comment: Sorry don't got that.

Comment: Sorry, I got frustrated using String#encode for your question. And I tried to sympathize while being funny (through saying that this is not a fun task). Obviously I failed :)

Comment: Oh sorry. :P English is not my primary language. I will try again to see if I can find out the problem. Thank you anyway. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally used *transliterate* from Rails ActiveSupport:

```
require 'active_support/all'
v = ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate v.downcase
v.gsub(/[^a-z1-9]+/, '-').chomp('-')
```

Works fine.

Comment: Looks like you need to add the magic encoding comment at the beginning of your ruby file `# coding: utf-8`

Comment: Sorry my bad. But are you sure you place the magic comment in the right place? I just did a simple test with a meaningless migration, `p "éíóúñ ".gsub(/é/, 'e')`. Without the magic comment, I got the `invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)`, as expected. And with the magic comment, it's ok. I'm running ruby 1.9.2 & rails 3.2.11

Comment: I did also a test apart and it works. But it does not so on the file I am working. Very strange.